# Цикл for. Есть ли возможность в цикле перебросить входящее значение на другой объект?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for, backend

Есть часть кода. В цикл с фронта будут приходить страницы, которые сравниваются с количеством страниц в книге с массива и по результату, если количество входящих страниц больше, чем страниц в книге - она закрывается.
Вопрос: можно ли реализовать, что бы разницу страниц(переполнение) перебрасывать на следующую книгу в массиве?

```
        for (let i = 0; i < training.books.length; i++) {
      book = await Book.findOne({ _id: training.books[i] });

      if (book?.numberOfPages === book?.readPages) {
        continue;
      }

      book.readPages += pages;

      if (book.readPages > book.numberOfPages) {
        book.readPages = book.numberOfPages;
      }

      await book.save();

      break;
    }
...
    });
```

Например пришло 25 страниц c  `const { pages: 25 } = req.body;`

они попадают в `book.readPages += pages;` первой книги

после чего сравнивается прочитанные страницы `book.readPages: 25`

со страницами в книге у которой общее количество страниц 15 `book.numberOfPages: 15`

и через if в коде выше  если `book.readPages > book.numberOfPages` то `book.readPages = book.numberOfPages`

и в ответе приходит по первой книге
`{readPages: 15, numberOfPages: 15}`

как оставшиеся 10 страниц перебросить в `book.readPages: 10` второй книги у которой `book.numberOfPages: 99`

и при следующем `const { pages: 25 } = req.body;`

у второй книги уже в `book.readPages: 35`, а не `book.readPages: 25`

надеюсь уточнил вопрос

=======================

Попробовал, нужного мне результата нет, после ввода

`const { pages: 49 } = req.body;`

пришел ответ

```
{
   "date": "2021-04-22 19:42:45",
   "pageCount": 49
 }
```

книга1 закрылась как и раньше

```
"book1": {
            "readPages": 45,
            "numberOfPages": 45,         
        }
```

при следующем добавлении

`const { pages: 7 } = req.body;`

ответ

```
{
  "date": "2021-04-22 19:42:45",
  "pageCount": 49
},
{
   "date": "2021-04-22 19:52:37",
   "pageCount": 7
 }
```

книга2 получает в readPages только второй запрос, разница в 4 страницы в нее не попала

```
"book2": {
            "readPages": 7,
            "numberOfPages": 19,         
        }
```

UPD

```
if (book?.numberOfPages === book?.readPages) {
    // totalPages -= book.numberOfPages; здесь нужен ?
    continue;
  }
```

здесь не нужно

Comment: «пришло 25» — а пришло оно как?) В какой переменной хранится число - ту и надо уменьшать в цикле.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME уточнил вопрос, надеюсь он поможет дать ответ))

Answer (score 0):

Нужна внешняя переменная, которая будет хранить сумму всех прилетевших страниц. Пробуйте:

```js
let totalPages = 0;
// Число может храниться и в каком-то объекте / файле.

const { pages } = req.body;
totalPages += pages; // <--

/***/
for (let i = 0; i < training.books.length; i++) {
  book = await Book.findOne({ _id: training.books[i] });

  if (book?.numberOfPages === book?.readPages) {
    // totalPages -= book.numberOfPages; здесь нужен ?
    continue;
  }

  book.readPages += totalPages; // <--

  if (book.readPages > book.numberOfPages) {
    book.readPages = book.numberOfPages;
    totalPages -= book.numberOfPages; // <--
  }

  await book.save();

  break;
}
//...
```

Comment: Попробовал, результата нет, обновил тело вопроса, может еще будут варианты